# sigma algebras generated by a set

Tags: measure-theory

If $M$ is the sigma algebra generated by $E$, then $M$ is the union of the sigma algebras generated by $F$ as $F$ ranges over all countable subsets of $E$.

(**Hint**: Show that the latter object is a sigma algebra)

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I can show that the latter object is a sigma algebra. But after that I am stucked.

Comment: Did you tried bidirectional inclusion?

Comment: Put that information in your question so we here can focus on where you are stuck.

Comment: Yes I tried but failed to show that

Comment: This has been asked at least twice in the last month or so.

Answer (score 2):

For any countable subset $\mathcal{C}$ of $\mathcal{E}$ it is evident
that $\sigma\left(\mathcal{C}\right)\subseteq\sigma\left(\mathcal{E}\right)$.
So also the union of these $\sigma\left(\mathcal{C}\right)$ is a
subset of $\sigma\left(\mathcal{E}\right)$. Secondly this union is
a $\sigma$-algebra (as you have shown yourself) that contains $\mathcal{E}$. Then
consequently $\sigma\left(\mathcal{E}\right)$ is a subset of
this union. Proved is now that $\sigma\left(\mathcal{E}\right)$ and
this union coincide.

Here in general $\sigma\left(\mathcal{A}\right)$ is a notation for the $\sigma$-algebra
generated by $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: How can we say that the union contains $\mathcal{E}$?

Comment: Let $e\in E$. Then a countable subset $C\subseteq E$ exists with $e\in C$ and consequently $e\in\sigma(C)$. Consequently $e\in U$ where $U$ denotes the union of these $\sigma$-algebras.

Comment: Oh I got it. Thanks drhab.